# Conditional operator with two different types based on type of template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function performing numeric calculations. In one place it processes doubles and in a second place it processes a custom arithmetic type. So the function is templated on the arithmetic type:

```
template<class T>
T calc(const T input_1)
{
    
}
```

If the function is templated on `double`, I need to convert `input_2` to `double`, otherwise if the template type is `MyNumber` `input_2` should remain.

I tried this with a conditional operator:

```
template<class T>
T calc(const T input_1)
{
    const MyNumber input_2 = getFromElsewhere();
    const T value = std::is_same_v<double, T> ? input_2.toDouble() : input_2;
    return value + input_1; // example
}
```

However, the above wouldn't compile because the two CMOV "branches" are different types (`double` vs `MyNumber`).

I replaced the conditional with a static if-else:

```
template<class T>
T calc(const T input_1)
{
    const MyNumber input_2 = getFromElsewhere();
    T value;

    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<double, T>)
    {
        value = input_2.toDouble();
    }
    else
    {
        value = input_2;
    }

    return value + input_1; // example
}
```

but I don't like removing `const` from `const T value`.

Is there a solution where I can switch the source of input based on the type of `T` and keep `const T value`?

Comment: what is `MyNumber` ? If there is a conversion from `double` to `MyNumber` the conditional should be fine https://godbolt.org/z/recTM1jqo. And if there is no conversion, i dont see how the `if else` would work. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: "but I don't like removing const from const T value." you can use a immediately invoked lambda expression

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai `MyNumber` is a decimal type but it doesn't have a constructor accepting double (because that gets tricky). It does convert to `double` though.

Comment: `const T value = [&]() { ... }();` and replace the `...` with your if statement

Answer (score 1):

you could call a templated function that is specialized for double.

```cpp
template<class T>
T inline unsafeConvert(const MyNumber& input_2)
{
    return input_2;
}

template<>
double inline unsafeConvert(const MyNumber& input_2)
{
    return input_2.toDouble();
}

template<class T>
T calc(const T input_1)
{
    const MyNumber input_2 = getFromElsewhere();
    const T value = unsafeConvert<T>(input_2);
    return value + input_1; // example
}
```

or you could have the templated convert function contain the `if constexpr` instead of defining the specialization

```cpp
template<class T>
T inline unsafeConvert(const MyNumber& input_2)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<double, T>)
    {
        return input_2.toDouble();
    }
    else
    {
        return input_2;
    }
}
```

another option as pointed by *463035818_is_not_an_ai*
in the comments is an immediately invoked lambda.

```
template<class T>
T calc(const T input_1)
{
    const MyNumber input_2 = getFromElsewhere();
    const T value = [&](){
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<double, T>)
    {
        return input_2.toDouble();
    }
    else
    {
        return input_2;
    }
    }();

    return value + input_1; // example
}
```

if your only special case is double and you are using this function once you should use the immediate lambda, but if you are reusing this function a lot then you should probably go with the template function route.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it by making `MyNumber` convertible into `double`, which means you can drop the `toDouble()` member function if you wish:

```cpp
class MyNumber {
public:
    //...
    explicit operator double() const { return m_value; }
    //...    
};
```

The implementation of `calc` will then not require any specialities except a `static_cast`, which will, if `T` is `MyNumber`, do nothing or else use the converting operator.

```cpp
template <class T>
T calc(const T input_1) {
    const T value = static_cast<T>(getFromElsewhere());

    return value + input_1;  // example
}
```

If `T` is neither `double` nor `MyNumber`, it will not compile, just as if you called `toDouble()` on a type (or non-type) lacking that member function.

You *can* however add more `explicit operator type () const` overloads for `float` etc to `MyNumber` without having to change `calc`. The `static_cast<T>` will then pick the correct one, so no need for a `toFloat()` etc.